# Convert Upper case html attributes to lower case html attributes using regularexpression

Tags: java, html

I am trying to convert uppercase html attributes to lower case in order to make my document to meet XHTML 1.0 ADA compliancy standards.

But i am not able to get the desired output.Below is the code snippet i have used to do this operation.Please help me.

```
private static String LowerCaseAttributes(String htmlfile){

        String[] attributes = new String[] { 
        "border-bottom", "margin", "padding","bgcolor","width", "border", 
        "style", "alt", "title", "for", "col", "header", "clear", 
        "colspan", "rows", "cols", "type", "name", "id", "target", "method" 
        }; 

        for(String s1 : attributes){ 
            htmlfile = htmlfile.replace(s1.toUpperCase() + "=", s1 + "="); 
        } 
        return htmlfile; 
    }
```

Comment: What output are you getting?  Can you give a short example input file and its corresponding output?

Comment: You are not using regexps here since you use `replace` and not `replaceAll`. They are not needed in this case anyway. Could you post an example of input that does not work with your code?

Comment: <DIV style="BORDER-BOTTOM: medium none; BORDER-LEFT: medium none; BACKGROUND-COLOR: transparent; MARGIN-TOP: 4px; WIDTH: 98%; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 4px; BORDER-TOP: medium none; BORDER-RIGHT: medium none" id=footerEditor sizcache="5776" sizset="1">----This is the example input even though this just one line of my whole document.Output is also same.No change.And I am using this regular expression in reference to http://madskristensen.net/post/Convert-HTML-tags-to-lower-case-for-XHTML-compliance.aspx

Comment: @Uppi **edit your question** and put responses for more code and details in the question, not in a comment, it will have no context and many people don't read the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using "=" in your replace method, when in your input it has ":".

Try this:

```
    for(String s1 : attributes){ 
        htmlfile = htmlfile.replaceAll(s1.toUpperCase() + ":", s1 + ":"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As told by @c0deNinja you need to use the `:` instead of `=`. Also the attribute list you defined has only `BORDER-BOTTOM` which might match in the sample string you gave in the comments. The rest of the items `BORDER-LEFT,BACKGROUND-COLOUR` etc are not there in your attribute list which you defined as a `String[]`. So you may not have seen those. Try to add the whole list.

Comment: yeah.I just posted sample there.I thought to change all attributes  if i can make it work.Now I changed everything.thanks anyway.